# Running MGWT in Super Dev Mode does not pick up code changes

Tags: gwt, mgwt, dev-mode, gwt-dev-mode, gwt-super-dev-mode

I was evaluating MGWT for the new mobile version of our website. So I downloaded the MGWT's showcase project and set it up in my Eclipse. I was able to compile the project and run it. I was then trying to set up the showcase to run in the Super Dev Mode environment which would help improve the development speed a lot. I followed the steps in Daniel's blog: http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/07/mgwt-super-dev-mode.html.

Everything was fine. I was able to start the Codeserver. I was able to see the Super Dev Mode popup when I opened up the app. I was able to request the Codeserver to recompile and I could see the compilation messages in the console. I could also see the generated JS files of the recompilation.

However, it seemed that the Codeserver did not pick up the changes I made. I tried to change a simple text, then asked the Codeserver to recompile, but the changes did not show after the recompilation. When I checked the new generated JS files, I could see that the Codeserver still used the old code to recompile.

When I restarted the Codeserver, the changes were recompiled correctly and I could see them in the app.

If anyone has a clue of what I might have done wrong, please let me know. I appreciate your help very much.

Thanks

Comment: You can post the above comment as answer and close the question selecting your own answer :) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just happened to find a solution to my own question:

Instead of adding the source folder to the classpath of the Codeserver run config as in Daniel's [instructions](http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/07/mgwt-super-dev-mode.html), I added this source folder as part of the command line arguments using the **-src** argument (see [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode) for more info).

So the arguments string for the Codeserver launch config should look like:

```
-bindAddress <codeserver-ip-address> -src <gwt-source-path> <gwt-module-name>
```